# Problems when Navbar expands (other itens are going down together)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making my first project as a programmer, and I found myself with a trouble that I'm not making to solve.

I made a navbar that expands. But, when it is expanding, other elements are going down too. I don't know the reason, and after two days trying to solve the problem, I got no success.

Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwjUB.jpg) that illustrates the situation:

Then, here is my code:

```
<header id="aermenu" class="sticky-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div id="saudacoes" class="col-1 order-lg-1 order-2 align-self-center">
                <p class="pt-3">Saudações, <br/> <span>Usuário</span></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-8 col-2 offset-lg-1 order-lg-2 order-1">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler mt-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menubar">
                        <span class="fas fa-bars text-white"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menubar">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="aeraer.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="aerhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="aerhvr(this,'off')">
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-aer.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btaer"/>
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-aer-on.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btaeron"/>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="aerlogin.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="loginhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="loginhvr(this,'off')">
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-login.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btlogin"/>
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-login-on.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btloginon"/>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="aerplay.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="playhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="playhvr(this,'off')">
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-play.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btplay"/>
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-play-on.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btplayon"/>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="aerequipe.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="equipehvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="equipehvr(this,'off')">
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-equipe.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btequipe"/>
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-equipe-on.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btequipeon"/>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="aerrank.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="rankhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="rankhvr(this,'off')">
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-rank.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btrank"/>
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-rank-on.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btrankon"/>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="aercontato.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="contatohvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="contatohvr(this,'off')">
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-contato.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btcontato"/>
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-contato-on.png" class="img-fluid btd"id="btcontatoon"/>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>

            <div class="col-2 order-3 align-self-center ml-auto d-none d-sm-block">
                <div class="justify-items-end" >
                    <img src="imagens/joker-sign.png" class="img-fluid jsign"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

If someone could help me to understand where I'm making some mistake, I would be grateful.

(Also, if you need to me to bring here other parts of the code, like CSS or JS, just tell me. I really think the problem is with the HTML part, but I don't know where).

Comment: can you provide images and why you make different `nav-brand` ?

Comment: I believe I didn't undertstand your comment. I already uploaded an image, and I didn't use the `nav-brand` because there is no brand logo in my code.

Comment: i want to say, can you provide pen or fiddle of your project, so we will help you

Comment: I tried to make a Fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/tc8xbspm/2/)

Comment: bro give me working example of your problem,

Comment: can you satisfy with my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made it for you, content is not exactly you want but i give you idea of that,

if you need logo in your right side simply add your image after `navbar-toggler` class so it pull right and for your `p tag name called Saudações, <br/> <span>Usuário` give it class `mr-auto` so it pull left and give additional margin you want.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <p class="mr-auto ml-5">Saudações, <br/> <span>Usuário</span></p>
    <img class="navbar-brand" style="width: 50px;" src="pdfs/img/lol1.jpg">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```